# Unable to use the user defined element in the if-elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I just want to convert minutes or days given by the user into hours.
It is showing that "minute is not defined". When I print the user input, minute is getting printed, but when I want to use that "minute" given by user in the if statement, then it is showing an error.

```
t_in = input("Is your input in minute or hr or day? ")
print (t_in)
t = input("Enter the value: ")
if t_in == minute:
    t = (1/60)*float(t)
elif t_in == day:
    t = (1/24)*float(t)
print(t)
```

Error message :

```
NameError: name 'minute' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the minute without the "", which means the minute is a variable, but you don't have a minute variable. You should write the minute in "" because it is a string, not a variable.

```
t_in = input("Is your input in minute or hr or day? ")
print (t_in)
t = input("Enter the value: ")
if t_in == "minute":
    t = (1/60)*float(t)
elif t_in == "day":
    t = (1/24)*float(t)
print(t)
```

and you can write this code shortly, like this

```
t_in = input("Is your input in minute or hr or day? ")
print (t_in)
t = input("Enter the value: ")
t = (1/60)*float(t) if t_in == "minute" else t = (1/24)*float(t)
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you haven't actually defined the variable "minute" nor have u defined "day" as a variable. While you are equating `t_in`to `minute` and `elif` as `day`, python is looking for the variable.. but you havent defined the variable and you also dont need to define..
You just need to make the minute and day a string by wrapping them by "minute" "days"
bcs `t_in` accepts the string value.

```
t = input("Enter the value: ")
if t_in == 'minute':
    t = (1/60)*float(t)
elif t_in == 'day':
    t = (1/24)*float(t)
print(t)
```

and also define a statement for 'hr' as an input for the completion of your code. if you want to :)